Alpha Mixing condition for moving average of a alpha mixing process (not necessarily stationary)
I recently facing the mixing processes. I know that the average of an alpha mixing when it is not i.i.d., it is not alpha mixing. But here I am asking about its moving average in the sense that $Y_t = \sum_{s=1}^T b_{s,t} X_t X_s$, when $b_{s,t}$ is a Gaussian kernel function and $X_s$ is an alpha mixing process but not necessarily stationary. So $b_{s,t}$ is weighting each $X_s$ base on its distance from observation t. So the $b_{s,t} = K\left(\frac{|s-t|}{T}\right)$ is a function of distance between observation s and t.
Intuitively, I can imagine that $Y_t$ and $Y_{t+n}$ can be independent as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $b_{s,t}$ gives the weights in a way that some observations weights are close to zero in one of them while they have a high weight in the other. So it seems $Y_t$ is also alpha mixing.
I want to see whether this intuition is correct or not, and if it is, how it can be proved, or at least how I should approach the proof.

For fixed $T$, the process $(Y_t)$ cannot be mixing. For example, if $T=1$, then
$$Y_t=b_{1,t}X_1.$$
Since $b_{1,t}\neq 0$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y_t$ is the same as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1$ hence
$(Y_t)$ would be $\alpha$-mixing only if $X_1$ is constant.
For the new version of the process, still with $T=1$, one has
$$
Y_t=b_{1,t}X_t X_1.
$$
In general, such a process is not $\alpha$-mixing. For example, if $X_t$ takes the value $1$ and $0$ with probability $1/2$ and $(X_t)$ is independent, then $\{Y_t=b_{1,t}\}=\{X_t=1\}\cap \{X_1=1\}$
and $\{Y_2=b_{1,2}\}=\{X_2=1\}\cap \{X_1=1\}$. For $t>2$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(\{Y_t=b_{1,t}\}\cap \{Y_2=b_{1,2}\})=2^{-3},
$$
$$
\mathbb P(\{Y_t=b_{1,t}\} )\mathbb P(   \{Y_2=b_{1,2}\})=2^{-4}
$$
hence $\alpha\left(\sigma(Y_t),\sigma(Y_2)\right)\geqslant 1/16$.

Thank you for your answer. What if I had an $X_t$ inside the summation? (This is my original problem. I edited the question, thank you.)
In this case, does the counterexample work?

@Farhad An adaptation works, see the edit.

Thank you very much; you made it easy to understand.

You are welcome.
